# Invoking a method without rediecting using a button mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

So im facing a problem here. I have a button that i want a method be run of. I see on there examples that i sould use Ajax here is my code.

This is what i was first trying

```
<button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-link reputation-buttons votes_manager increase" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("MessageReputationUp", "Forum", new { groupId = Model.GroupId, threadId = Model.ThreadId, messageId = Model.Id })';return false;" disabled>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
                    </button>
```

The problem is that is a URL and it will redirect me what i dont want. So than i came up with this.

```
<button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-link reputation-buttons votes_manager decrease" onclick="location.href='@Ajax.ActionLink(" " , "MessageReputationDown", "Forum", new { groupId = Model.GroupId, threadId = Model.ThreadId, messageId = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })';return false;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
                    </button>
```

But that it starts giving me weird text. it will show me : " "> Expect of nothing. What i want to do is run a method in the controller. Without the page doing anything. So no reloading no redirecting just nothing.

EDIT

Maybe i sould give a bit more context to the code its for a reputation system. It looked like this:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-link reputation-buttons votes_manager increase" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("MessageReputationUp", "Forum", new { groupId = Model.GroupId, threadId = Model.ThreadId, messageId = Model.Id })';return false;" disabled>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div style="padding-left:9px;" class="displayer">@Model.Reputation.ToString()</div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-link reputation-buttons votes_manager decrease" onclick="location.href='@Ajax.ActionLink(" " , "MessageReputationDown", "Forum", new { groupId = Model.GroupId, threadId = Model.ThreadId, messageId = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })';return false;" disabled>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
                    </button>
```

This code is not a single pice of code its replicated a lot of times and it has some jquery scripts already

```
$(function () {

$(document).on('click', '.votes_manager', function () {
    var elem = $(this).parent().parent().children('.displayer');
    var value = parseInt(elem.text());
    if ($(this).hasClass('increase')) {
        ++value;
    }
    else {
        --value;
    }
    elem.text(value);
});
```

});

$(function () {

```
$(document).on('click', '.votes_manager', function () {
    var elem1 = $(this).parent().parent().children('.increase');
    var elem2 = $(this).parent().parent().children('.decrease');
    elem1.prop('disabled', true);
    elem2.prop('disabled', true);
});
```

});

$("#reputation").click(function (e) {

```
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({

    url: $(this).attr("href"), // comma here instead of semicolon   
    success: function () {
        alert("Value Added");  // or any other indication if you want to show
    }

});
```

});

Comment: as you mentioned in the beginning, you should use Ajax.

Comment: But how that i sould use im am trying but like i said i dont want any linktext

Answer (score 0):

You could reload by ajax just the part that you want, like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MessageReputationUp", "Forum", new { groupId = Model.GroupId, threadId = Model.ThreadId, messageId = Model.Id },
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "post",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, // this will substitute in way async ajax way (without refresh) 
    UpdateTargetId = "ElementToBeSubstituted" // like a table or div
}))
{
    <button type="submit" class="btn-xs btn-link reputation-buttons votes_manager increase">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
    </button>    
}
```

I hope it helps.

In your controller you should put this:

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
 {
    return PartialView("_EmployeeTable", model);
 }
```

This partial view will be the content that will be replaced for your element.

Comment: Yes i helps but is there a option with less code? Since i have to use that button 4 times. If there is not than thanks anywhay

Comment: I put it in a more descriptive mode to be easy to explain, but the `using ` as I use it´s just one line.

Comment: Okay but the method needs to have the groupid and the threadid. Can i use this like a Html.BeginForm ?

Comment: Yep that looks about it im going to test it now

Comment: Nope it does not work. Its still redirecting me to a empty webpage.

Comment: Ohh now i see i need to put there a Id. I cant because this is replicated multiple times. So i cant use Ids.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the model values to the javascript variables and then pass the values to controller using Jquery ajax call as a Querystring as shown below.

```
<button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-link reputation-buttons votes_manager decrease" onclick="javascript: callController();return false;">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></button>

<script>
var groupId ='@Model.GroupId';
var threadId ='@Model.ThreadId';
var messageId ='@Model.Id';

function callController(){
//call to controller
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Forum/MessageReputationDown?groupId='+groupId+'&threadId='+threadId+'&messageId='+messageId,
        dataType: 'html',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (error) {
           alert(error);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

controller

```
public class ForumController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MessageReputationDown(string groupId,string threadId, string messageId)
    {
        return Json("success");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope not working. Its has a popup that sould not be there. But its not calling the method also.

Comment: Okay did a bit more testing and up works but down fails. And all my other jquery code stops working

Comment: i have added the controller code as well might be the issue with the parameter type

Comment: No it does not rember there are 2 buttons one for up and one for down. The up one works the down one does not and it still kills all my other jquery code.

Comment: I already did i edit the post but here it is again. Or i cant becasue its too long

Comment: i didnt find the Id #reputation anywhere in the code but you are trying to for onclick event. I am not able to get what is the use there

Comment: There is no Id. Becasue this code is replicated a lot of times in the html document since that the id wont be unique

Comment: but you are trying for an onclick event for the id #reputation and inside that you calling the controller using ajax that might be the issue

Comment: instead id try the class name to trigger the click event

Comment: Look let me make is super simple i want a Void Method to be run without refreshing the page. It needs to replutedated so it needs to know what it click it sould edit that not anything else. So id dont work since they wont be uniqe.

Comment: Yes But i got a idea you see the code $(function () {

$(document).on('click', '.votes_manager', function () {
    var elem = $(this).parent().parent().children('.displayer');
    var value = parseInt(elem.text());
    if ($(this).hasClass('increase')) {
        ++value;
    }
    else {
        --value;
    }
    elem.text(value);
});
}); I think i can use that